# file transfer automation

Tags: scp

Server A generates a file and scp's it to Server B.  I have cron running on Server B that each minute looks for new files that were copied over.  My question is- how can Server B ensure that the file that was copied over is actually *done* being copied?  I don't want to start processing the file unless it's been fully written to.  Is this possible to determine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCP it over under a temporary name and then rename it to its proper name, as the move will be an atomic process.

Comment: works for me!  great idea!